# Before_update callback is getting called using updated attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why is the before_update callback using the updated params? Shouldn't it be using the original params?

I have a `Round` model that `belongs_to` a `Case` model (the `Case` `has_many` `Rounds`)

Some of the attributes of the `Case` are calculated via the `Round`'s callbacks. For example, when there is a new `Round` that was a win, the `Case`'s wins attribute gets increased by 1.

I'm having an issue with callbacks now that I need to update my case. I have a method `add_round` and `delete_round` within the `Round` model that add and remove the attributes of a given round respectively.

To clarify, **delete_round and add_round do not actually delete or create the round**, they delete or add the stats of the round to the cases' attributes

Here's my round model:

```
class Round < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :case

  after_save     :add_round
  before_update  :delete_round
  before_destroy  :delete_round

  private
    # Adds this Round's stats to its Case
    def add_round
      self.case.add_round(self)
    end

    # Deletes this Round's stats from its Case
    def delete_round
      self.case.delete_round(self)
    end
end
```

And here's the case model:

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :rounds,     dependent: :destroy

  def add_round(round)
    if round.win?
      update_attribute(wins: wins + 1)
    else
      update_attribute(losses: losses + 1)
    end
    update_attribute(win_percentage: 100 * wins / (wins + losses)
  end

  def delete_round(round)
    if round.win?
      update_attribute(wins: wins - 1)
    else
      update_attribute(losses: losses - 1)
    end
    update_attribute(win_percentage: 100 * wins / (wins + losses)
  end
end
```

and the schema:

```
create_table "cases", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",                              null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                              null: false
  t.integer  "wins",                      default: 0
  t.integer  "losses",                    default: 0
  t.float    "win_percentage",            default: 0.0
end

create_table "rounds", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "case_id"
  t.boolean  "win"
  t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
end
```

Here's rough, pseudo-code-ish example of what I want to happen:

```
case = Case.create(wins: 0, losses: 0, win_percentage: 0)
round = Round.create(win: true, case_id: case.id)

# add_round is called

case.wins = 1
case.losses = 0
case.win_percentage = 100

round.update_attribute(win: false)

# before that parameter is updated, delete_round is called on the round with the old attributes

case.wins = 0
case.losses = 0
case.win_percentage = 0

# after that parameter is updated, add_round is called on the updated round

case.wins = 0
case.losses = 1
case.win_percentage = 0

round.destroy

# delete_round is called

case.wins = 0
case.losses = 0
case.win_percentage = 0
```

Once they are updated, add the round with the new parameters

For some reason, before_update is getting sent the updated attributes. Why is this happening? How should I change the callbacks?

Comment: I could not understand, what you want is to delete round when case is updated? or is there more things?

Comment: or delete round when round is updated???

Comment: I want to delete the old version of the round from the cases' stats, then add the new version. In other words, updating a round from a win to a loss is the same thing as deleting that win, then adding the loss. Should have been clearer: delete_round and add_round don't delete the actual rounds, they delete the stats of that round from the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call delete_round for both before_validation and before_save. before_save is called in both case: on update and on create.
If you want to call delete_round only on update, you have to tell:

`before_update    :delete_round`

or

`before_save    :delete_round, on: :update`

**Updated**

The problem is in the way your call your callbacks and the logic of your methods:

`after_save     :add_round
before_update  :delete_round`

Only on create your 'after_save :add_round' will be called without calling delete_round in before_update. And they will be called on the same object in a single transaction. So, in most cases first you will be calling delete_round and then add_round. And since they are doing the reverse operations you will end up with no changes.

What you actually want to do is to call processing of your results only once, so your method will be something like this:

`def process_round(round)
  result = round.win? ? 1 : -1
  update_attribute(wins: wins + result)
  update_attribute(losses: losses - result)
end`

And I doubt that type of callback changes much, so you can only after_save for example:

In your Round class:

`after_save :process_round`

**Updated**

Another way to separate your add_round and delete_round actions is to use conditional callbacks like this:

class Round < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :case

before_update  :add_round, if: win?

before_update  :delete_round, unless: win?

before_destroy  :delete_round

private

```
# Adds this Round's stats to its Case
def add_round
  self.case.add_round(self)
end

# Deletes this Round's stats from its Case
def delete_round
  self.case.delete_round(self)
end
```

end

It is probably what you actually need.

Comment: Oops, there was a typo in my post. Updated it to show what it is now. Anyway, when I call `:delete` round on `before_update`, the parameters passed to it are the updated ones. So instead of deleting the old round, it deletes the new one then adds the new one, so nothing actually changes.

Comment: It is difficult to tell with your pseudo code. Can you post your code for models? Only models with the callbacks and their implementation.

Comment: Sure, I updated the post to include the relevant info in the models and the schema

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I created, in addition to the answer already provided:

```
  # Deletes this Round's stats from its Case
  def delete_round
    round = Round.new
    round.assign_attributes(self.attributes)
    round.assign_attributes(self.changed_attributes)
    self.case.delete_round(round)
  end
```